# pgfplotstable or datatool?

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, datatool, database

What are differences, which to use for including `.csv`, `.tsv` files ?
Datatool ? pgfplotstable ?

I've seen at question : [How typeset a numeric table from a CSV file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24256/how-typeset-a-numeric-table-from-a-csv-file)

how person asked about fixing `datatool` issue, and answer was to use `pgfplotstable`

Are there other options for including tabular data into documents ?

What are advantages and disadvantages of possible choices ?

Comment: I've added a `datatool` solution to the linked question.

Answer (score 10):

Both `datatool` and `pgfplotstable` can do similar things, but `datatool` is designed as a more general tool and therefore can in principle do more things (e.g. form letters and the like).  So if your requirements are simply pretty printing tables directly from CSV files I might prefer `pgfplotstables` since it is especially designed for that, and if you are independently used to using TiKZ, has a nice key-value syntax that is very easy to use. If you have more complicated things you might need to do with your CSV data, then `datatool` might be a better choice.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you want to give LuaLaTeX a try. It's very easy to write a script to read external files and format LaTeX commands. It is good practice to write the lua functions in a separate file with the extension .lua. For this MWE I use the `filecontents` environment instead to provide an extra file for the lua script and the datafile.

Here is an other example for reading csv files with LuaLaTeX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41499/10570.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%create a datafile
\begin{filecontents*}{datafile.csv}
30.0,   0.0,    0.0
60.0,   1.9098, 5.8779
90.0,   6.9098, 9.5106
120.0,  13.09,  9.5106
150.0,  18.09,  5.8779
180.0,  20.0,   0.0
\end{filecontents*}

%create a lua script file
\begin{filecontents*}{luaFunctions.lua}
 function readDataFile()

    local input = io.open('datafile.csv', 'r')
    dataTable = {} --global table for storing the read values

    for line in input:lines() do

        --split the line with the comma delimiter 
        local split = string.explode(line, ",")

        --save the arguments in variables
        tableItem = {}
        tableItem.arg1 = split[1]
        tableItem.arg2 = split[2]
        tableItem.arg3 = split[3]

        --insert the arguments of one line in the table
        table.insert(dataTable, tableItem)
    end

    input:close()
 end


function printTable()
    tex.print(string.format("\\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}"))
    tex.print(string.format("Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3\\\\\\hline"))

    --create a latex string for every table entry
    for i,p in ipairs(dataTable) do
        tex.print(string.format(" {%s} & {%s} & {%s} \\\\",p.arg1, p.arg2, p.arg3))
    end

    tex.print(string.format("\\end{tabular}"))
end
\end{filecontents*}


% read the external lua file to declare the defined functions,
% but without execute the Lua commands and functions
\directlua{dofile("luaFunctions.lua")}

% latex commands to execute the lua functions
\def\readDataFile{\directlua{readDataFile()}}
\def\printTable{\directlua{printTable()}}

\begin{document}
\readDataFile
\printTable
\end{document}
```

Comment: In future I am planning to try `LuaLaTeX` as I've programmed in past in `Lua` and liked this scripting language a lot ! Currently I am working with book, with many custom typesettings tailored for pdflatex. So not now, but in future - I'd love to. Your example will be one of my starting points :).