# How can I draw a table with filename.dat file?

Tags: tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How typeset a numeric table from a CSV file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24256/how-typeset-a-numeric-table-from-a-csv-file)

I wonder if there is a possibility to use a dat file and create a table with it (like plots in gnuplot). for example my first data column there is a name.dat how can use it to create first column of table?

Comment: You can use the [`pgfplotstable`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplotstable) package.

Comment: If you are interested in LuaLaTeX maybe this will help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44278/10570.

Comment: You can find more information on what @Harish said at the [faq#howtoask] ("How to ask").