# Creating table from file dat

Tags: tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How typeset a numeric table from a CSV file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24256/how-typeset-a-numeric-table-from-a-csv-file)

I'm asking if it exists a package to extract data from file (txt or dat) and create a table throughout those data. Similar things for the case of command file in pgfplots

Comment: You may be interested in `datatool` and `pgfplotstable`.

Comment: Related (duplicate?) question: [How to typeset a numeric table from a CSV file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24256/2693). See also  [pgfplotstable or datatool?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44105/2693).