# Is there a way to call a spreadsheet (excel, google sheets, etc.) directly on a latex document?

Tags: tables, excel, libre-office

I would like to know if there is a way, some package, to directly call my spreadsheets directly in a latex document, just as it is done with images. This would be very useful. That way, any data changes could be made directly in the spreadsheet file.

**Update 1**

I tried `pgfplotstable`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
    
    
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        every head row/.style={ before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        columns/Fruit/.style={string type},
        columns/Animal/.style={string type}
        ]
        {   
            Number Fruit Animal
            1.23456 Banana Dog
            2.871 Orange Cat
            3.141592 Apple Bear
        } % A file can be called here too 

\end{document}
```

I took the PgfplotsTable package manual as a reference (http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplotstable.pdf).

I put the table as plain text, but a CSV file can be called as well.

It works fine!

Comment: it’s possible to export spreadsheet data as a CSV and read that as text, or to export it as an image and include that. If I understand you correctly. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Thank you for the replay @Davislor. Imagine a document that you need to update frequently. The document presents some parameters through tables. Usually, these tables are built in advance using an application such as excel, libre-office or google sheet. In a conventional workflow, I have to convert these tables to latex or turn them into images to insert into the document. I wanted something that imports the tables directly from the files. Something like `\inputspreadsheet{table.xlsx}{"A1:B5"}`.

Comment: You might export to CSV and read that in with `pgfplotstable`, `datatool` or [direct Lua](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44105/pgfplotstable-or-datatool).

Comment: Thank you again @Davislor! I will try these tools and post the result here.

Answer (score 1):

TeX is Turing-complete so anything computable can be done with it, but it's probably easiest to use LuaLaTeX to accomplish the task. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139003/how-to-read-and-parse-excel-files-in-lua) at the main StackExchange site goes into how to use Lua to read an Excel file. As far as I know, there is no package which wraps up this functionality nicely.

Other solutions require an export step from the Excel (whether writing to CSV or using a tool like [excel2latex](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex) which is an .xla plugin which will write LaTeX directly from Excel.