# Recommendation for Collecting Feedback on Numerous Files

Tags: best-practices

Before I go down the path of the solution I am thinking of, I thought I should solicit feedback/suggestions as others must have come across this situation before.

### Background:

I have hundreds of separate PDF files (all generated by LaTeX) over various levels of hierarchy that are cross linked via `\href`. I would like to come up with a system that I can give a hierarchical directory structure containing the PDF files and collect feedback from reviewers on the content of the files.

### Considerations:

- Assume that reviewers do NOT have s/w installed to process the source `.tex` files.
- Need to know that every file was actually looked at.
- Manage feedback from several users.
- A Unix (MacOS) only solution is acceptable but would prefer one that could also work on Windows.

### References:

- I proposed a similar process for creating/managing numerous external files in [Automating error message references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60066/4301), so this solution for collecting feedback would be usable in a situation such as that.

### Solution being Considered:

- As part of the build process that generates the PDFs, I would copy the PDFs into a separate directory tree, and also create a parallel directory structure that contains *empty* `.txt` (not `.tex`) files with the same file name as the corresponding `.pdf` file.

  Reason for a separate directory for the feedback is so that I just need to get the feedback directory from the reviewers.    The links in the PDFs are all relative so as long as the hierarchy is maintained the links will still work.
- Provide a click able link in each file (**REVIEW** button) that will open the corresponding `.txt` with `Edit` on the Mac, and perhaps `WordPad` on a PC.  Reviewers enter their comments and `Save` the file.

  On the Mac I would `touch` the file before opening it to ensure that the time stamp was updated, and the user would only be required to close the file.  Am assuming that there is something similar on Windows. This would handle the case of where the file was reviewed but no comments were necessary.
- Once I get the review directories back, I iterate through my `.tex` file hierarchy and produce an output file that contains a link to the source `.tex` file and a link to each reviewer's `.txt` file. I would color code this so that I could distinguish between the cases of:

  1. File not reviewed: The time stamp of `.txt` file has not changed since the build time.
  2. File approved (i.e, was looked at but no comments made on it): The time stamp of the `.txt` file has changed, but the file is empty.
  3. Comments were made on this file: The time stamp of the `.txt` file has changed, and the file is not empty.

Would be interested in any alternate suggestions, or how to improve this process.

Comment: Use Moodle.  Treat each file as a short answer quiz question. Moodle will collect all the answers (feedback) for each question (pdf file) and link them with the individual students (reviewers).   Date stamps etc. automatically.  Essentially using Moodle as a CVS for reviewer comments.   It is also possible to write you own processing routines for the data or to format it convenient for LateX later.